# Odd entities in generated text (chrome is weird)

Tags: php, html, image, google-chrome, entities

I am working on a school-project with two classmates. Our task is to make a dynamic gallery for web.
So we got the whole gallery up and running perfect, except chrome is acting mighty weird about it.
We have our pictures uploaded in blob, as well as our thumbnails. We load them from the database through php.

```
<div id="content_right">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['c'])) {
$c = $_GET['c'];
$thumbs_sql = mysql_query("SELECT foto_id
     FROM `fotos`
     INNER JOIN foto_cat ON fotos.foto_cat = foto_cat.cat_id
     WHERE fotos.foto_cat = $c");
}
else{
$thumbs_sql = mysql_query("SELECT foto_id 
     FROM fotos 
     INNER JOIN foto_cat ON fotos.foto_cat = foto_cat.cat_id
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8");
}
while($getthumbs = mysql_fetch_array($thumbs_sql))
{
 $thumb_id = $getthumbs["foto_id"];
 $picsource = 'inc/thumbnails.php?thumb='.$thumb_id;
 $thumb .= '<div class="ikon">
 <img alt="'.$thumb_id.'" src="'.$picsource.'" value="inc/picture.php?pic='.$thumb_id.'" />
</div>';
}
echo $thumb;
?>
</div>
```

The thing is, it works perfect in any browser but chrome. The problem is the browser (or server) seems to add a very odd entity in our file-source (for the img-tag). It cannot be displayed in the page source, neither by echoing the source out. It is only visible through chromes developer tools, and shows up as a square (unknown entity?). It is placed right after "inc/".

[image] (picture-example of the problem in chrome developer tools.)

Not only does this seem strange, but also, it works perfect in chrome when we use a localhost (wamp/mamp/xampp etc.). Likewise, the image can still be downloaded/viewed if hardcoded into either url bar or source.
We have tried converting it to string, adding the slash through php, setting enctype and anything else we could possibly think of.
This leads us to believe it must be a serverside problem? Are we mistaken?
And if not, is there a workaround through coding?

The gallery is live at http://46246.rtsphp.dk/gallery/index.php.
Let me know if you need more files than this somehow, or anything else. Any help would be greatly appreciated, since we ourselves are clueless :S

~Esben Tind (esbentind at gmail dot com)

Comment: That's probably because you use dirty language in your HTML comments :D (sorry, couldn't contain myself)

Comment: Please use mysql_real_escape string() over that $c used in the query.

Comment: danish_manners(!$care); , slut in danish means end. ;) (pretty funny though I rofld)

Comment: Actually, it looks perfectly fine on my machine (Google Chrome unstable on debian lenny x86). Except the fact that the images don't load, but the URI does not contain anything strange. Retrieving the page through wget didn't yield anything odd either.

Answer (score 3):

This is a serverside issue. Your thumbnails.php script is sending the following header:

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=nytaar1.jpg

This makes the browser try to download the file. I'd suggest searching for that in thumbnails.php and removing it.

Comment: thanks for clearing up on the downloading of the image, although it did no solve the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to HTML-encode all values you use in HTML, using the `htmlspecialchars()` function, like so:

```
<img alt="'.htmlspecialchars($thumb_id).'" src="'.htmlspecialchars($picsource).'" value="inc/picture.php?pic='.htmlspecialchars($thumb_id).'" />
```

Otherwise, if any of the values by any chance contains & characters or similar, you produce invalid HTML, and the output is undefined - some browsers may guess correctly what you meant, others will mis-guess or simply refuse to render your HTML.

Comment: sorry, I tried it out but it did absolutely nothing for me in this case.

Comment: Seeing the screenshot, I too doubt that HTML-encoding is going to solve anything.